# MongoDB types in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

Is there a node.js module that allows my application to have the same types as MongoDB:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/

For example, in my node.js app, I want it to have full understanding of the Integer type, but node.js doesn't recognize anything but Number out of the box to my understanding.

Comment: Who would vote to close this perfectly good question?  It's extremely clear, on topic, and very relevant.

Comment: seriously, thanks Brad for backing me up

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but we really found mongoose a very helpful layer for keeping us standardized on data and data types. At the very least, having a schema defined at least presented an agreed upon scheme between everyone.

Comment: If you don't find a package you could make your own based [on these internal functions in Meteor's mongo package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js#L67-L111).

Comment: I want to do type checking in my node.js app, so I can better interact with MongoDB. For example, if I try to insert the wrong type into MongoDB, MongoDB with throw an error. But if I do better upfront checks of the data in my app, I can catch the error before then. Duh. Since I am using Meteor, Mongoose is not the best solution. However, I have had good experience with Mongoose using Node.js with Express. However, I still don't think Mongoose solves the problem I hint at in the original question.

Comment: Well, to amend my previous comment, since Mongo is schemaless, it won't barf when you put the wrong type in; nevertheless I still want to do type checking / schema checking before I insert into the database. As far as Mongoose goes, it does have some MongoDB types included as far as I can tell http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Answer (score 3):

> node.js doesn't recognize anything but Number out of the box to my understanding.

Well, that's a design decision of JavaScript. JavaScript only has a `Number` type, which is, if the implementation follows the standard's recommendation, [represented as IEEE-754 double precision floating point number](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2). That hides much of the complexity of `short` vs. `long` vs. `float` vs. `double` and all the other numeric types that are common in most other languages. It's also a good compromise, because they have integer precision up to 2^53 - 1, so you rarely need something outside this range, most of the time, and if you do, a `long` usually doesn't cut it either...

MongoDB, on the other hand, is written in C++ and is thus much closer to the gritty details of how data is actually stored in memory. Bridging that gap isn't trivial.

> Is there a node.js module that allows my application to have the same types as MongoDB?

In a way, you're battling your underlying programming language. If such a module existed, it would also have to somehow implement a whole lot of *operations*, e.g. long addition (for results > 2^53-1) in a fundamentally different way. For instance, it could do this by converting the digits to a string and adding the individual digits manually, which would be atrociously slow.

Something like this happens in the mongo shell, e.g. for very long integers it uses a syntax like `NumberLong("1223")`. But it doesn't re-implement the *operations*, it falls back to regular V8 JavaScript. Proof:

```
> var foo = NumberLong("36028797018963968") // 2^55
> var foo2 = foo + NumberLong("1")
> foo2
36028797018963970 // should be 36028797018963969
```

Alternatively, such a module could be a *native module* that used the existing implementations of a native programming language such as C++. There's a [node module called 'edge' that apparently does it for C#](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge). However, that comes with quite a bit of complexity because crossing language borders requires [marshalling](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-marshal-data-between-c-and-nodejs), which is both expensive and tricky to get right.

In other words: getting a truly different set of types requires another programming language. Making your code *roughly* stick to your schema is possible, e.g. via mongoose or via coding discipline, but it won't make JS strongly typed.

Comment: thanks, I  think roughly sticking to the Mongo types is good enough. I don't have enough experience with MongoDB to know if MongoDB can be configured to throw errors if the wrong type is inserted into a document, but in any case the idea is to catch that in the application itself before that could happen. Exactly replicating the MongoDB types in JS might be both very complex and unnecessary, as you suggest. I agree that Mongoose is on the right track, I just want something that is Meteor-specific and a little bit better than Mongoose.

Comment: Well, MongoDB allows you to store documents that look entirely different in the same collection, so MongoDB itself can't be configured to enforce a schema.I'm unfortunately not an expert on Meteor or Node, but a quick search turned up Collection2 and its subproject https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema, and peerdb: https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-peerdb maybe that helps

Comment: Then I wonder why MongoDB has types at all - perhaps you can read the types when pulling in data to an application.

Comment: *everything* has types, unless you want pure binary data... a bunch of 0's and 1's could mean anything. In particular, you need ordered values for indexes to work, so you need comparison rules which aren't trivial... In any case, if you feel more comfortable with strongly typed languages, you might want to take a look at java, scala or C# or so - they're not too bad either ;-) There, you'd basically serialize an instance of a class and the mappings to MongoDB are clear (though there's still choices, e.g. dictionaries as objects or arrays).

Comment: I come from Java, but will be sticking to Node.js for now. I would be surprised if nobody from Node/Mongo has worked on something like this

Comment: So `@types/mongodb` does not make sense to "satisfy" `tsc`? Better use [`orm` for mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/using-typescript-with-mongodb-tutorial)